# How to generate the access Token to access the Proxy Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, microsoft-entra-id

How to generate the access Token to access the Proxy Application using AcquireTokenSilent method.
I have used the AcquireTokenSilent method but the method returns null result.

Below is the code snippet

```
var scopes = new string[] { todoListResourceId + "/user_impersonation" };

            AuthenticationResult authResult;
            //authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();

            try
            {
                authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
                //authResult = await 
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
            {
                authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            }
```

Here in** authResult ** i am getting null result.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the framework and version of your app?

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the following code to generate an access token to access a proxy application.*

**Code :**

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "<clientID>";
        string tenantId = "<tenantID>";
        string todoListResourceId = "<resourceID>";

        var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
            .Build();

        var accounts = await pca.GetAccountsAsync();
        var account = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

        if (account == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No accounts found. You need to sign in.");
        }
        else
        {
            var scopes = new string[] { todoListResourceId + "/user_impersonation" };
            AuthenticationResult authResult;

            try
            {
                authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                try
                {
                    authResult = await pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception interactiveEx)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Interactive authentication failed: {interactiveEx.Message}");
                    return;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {authResult.AccessToken}");
        }
    }
}
```

Before running the above code, you should grant access to the specified resource (todoListResourceId) with the required scope (user_impersonation).

**Output:**

The code ran successfully and generated the access token to access a proxy application.

[image: Access token output]